# Create a Flow to send and email alert everytime there's a new donation and everytime someone donates above $1K

Tags: visual-workflow

I've been trying to figure this out for days and it seems simple but I'm just not satisfied with the result of my solution so far. There must be something better. I have a Donation object that stores donation records. I want to send an email alert to a colleague every time there's a new donation as well as when there's a donation that is $1k or above. The email alerts use merge fields to capture donation records that will be used in the email.

Thank you so much for the guidance!

Here's my flow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... and?  is this not working?  What part isn't working? Where exactly are you stuck?  please edit your question to include a clear problem that can be solved.  Otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I tested it out. The donation was recorded in Salesforce. However, I did not receive the email alerts as expected. For example, I tested with a unique first-time donor with $1,010.00 and I did not receive the email alert for High Priority Donor. I tested it again with a different amount and I received the email alert for New Donor however some of the merge field values included in the email didn't appear such as the Donation Amount. Other merge fields are included though like the Donation Date.